# Builder annotation is not supporting in Kotlin multi-inheritance architecture

Tags: kotlin, multiple-inheritance, lombok, kotlin-android-extensions

**Lombok @SuperBuilder doesn't work for inheritance in kotlin use cases:**

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
open class Test1 : Test2() {

    @Nullable
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    private val id: Int? = null

    fun of(id: String?, code: String?, label: String?, sort: Int?): Test1 {
        return Test1.builder().id(id).code(code).label(label).sort(sort).build()
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Slf4j
@DiscriminatorValue("logging")
@Polymorphism
@SuperBuilder
open class Test2 : Test3() {
    @Nullable
    @JsonIgnore
    private val lngId: Int? = null

    @Nullable
    @JsonIgnore
    private val requestedLngId: Int? = null
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@MappedSuperclass
@Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.IMPLICIT)
@DiscriminatorValue("simple")
@SuperBuilder
open class Test3 {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private val id: String? = null

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private val code: String? = null

    @Nullable
    private val label: String? = null

    @Nullable
    private val sort: Int? = null
}
Test1.builder().id("36").code("code").label("label").build();
```

I am unable to retrieve the data present in the parent class . I am not sure how can I use the annotation @superbuilder with the above kotlin code for the above scenario. @superbuilder works fine with normal classes but not with classes from kotlin code

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to convert Java sources into Kotlin sources? Or do you want to use Lombok-enhanced Java classes from Kotlin code? Do you use the Lombok compiler plugin for Kotlin (`org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.lombok`)?

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Comment: I had added the kotlin code for better understanding. I am unableto implement Superbuilder annotation. please suggest a solution or an alternative for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok is an annotation processor designed for annotating Java sources. It does not work (and will probably never work) for Kotlin sources.

You have to use Java if you want to use `@SuperBuilder`. Furthermore, if you want to use Lombok-enhanced Java classes in Kotlin, make sure that you compile the Java sources with `javac` before compiling your Kotlin code.

Kotlin supports Lombok-annotated Java sources via the [Lombok compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lombok.html). However, this only works for a limited set of annotations, and only the declarations are generated. Thus, you still need a `javac` with Lombok to compile the Java sources afterwards.

Comment: Is there possible any way we can achieve the above goal in kotlin ?

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'm not a Kotlin expert. There probably is some fancy Kotlin-style pattern to achieve your goal with less and/or better code than manually  implementing a builder in Java. However, I doubt it will be as simple as `@SuperBuilder`.